# How should I create an object, copying optional properties only if they exist?

Tags: typescript, option-type

I'm writing code that maps objects between different domains. Often times, the objects have multiple optional fields, and I want to copy them if they exist. My attempts in the code below:

- `createFrom1`: works, but has a lot of repetition.
- `createFrom2`: Doesn't work - optional properties become `undefined`

How can I accomplish this?

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

```
interface type1 {
    mandatoryX: string; // plus more...
    optionalFoo?: string;
    optionalBaz?: string
}

interface type2 {
    mandatoryY: string; // plus more...
    optionalBar?: string;
    optionalBaz?: string
}

function createFrom(input: type1) : type2 {
    const output : type2 = {
        mandatoryY: input.mandatoryX,
    };

    if (input.optionalFoo != null) {
        output.optionalBar = input.optionalFoo;
    }

    if (input.optionalBaz != null) {
        output.optionalBar = input.optionalBaz;
    }

    return output;
}

function createFrom2(input: type1) : type2 {
    return {
        mandatoryY: input.mandatoryX,
        optionalBar: input.optionalFoo, // Doesn't work right - if input.optionalFoo is not defined, will create optionalBar: undefined
        optionalBaz: input.optionalBaz,
    };
}
```

Comment: You have added `different${Prop}` prefix to your return value. Is this by design ? Is there only one mandatory prop?

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZrjDm) works for you

Comment: @captain-yossarian: `optional1`/`differentOptional1` was supposed to demonstrate that the different domains have different names for the optional properties. I guess it wasn't clear - I'll edit and rename.

Comment: *Doesn't work right - if input.optionalFoo is not defined, will create optionalBar: undefined* – What else is it supposed to do? `{optionalBar: undefined}` is valid according to your interface, if you don't want `undefined` properties applied to the new object then use the first `createFrom()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
function createFrom2(input: type1) : type2 {
    return {
        mandatoryY: input.mandatoryX,
        ...input.optionalFoo && { optionalBar: input.optionalFoo }, 
        ...input.optionalBaz && { optionalBaz: input.optionalBaz },
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjATwA4QIzIN4BQyxyAtnCACZxgD2UaAGgFzIDOYUoA5gNzIB6AcgwAbAK5sy9CADp5RErQxhgtEHFEAxWrQD8rDlxB9FxZavWaAQnABeB9px4EAvgQ+hIsRCnRYAJnwzMgpqOgYATUNnE34hEQkpUhl5WRCLNQ1RWyhHIx5eDJUsm3t82O43DxhxEARLEGQEKAgaCC0oWlIAgApQDHEwVn8cAEpkEcwIIMISZFawcSgmufmScioaejRo5AGh2U3wncYAGhD5tIOwWUyrbV1kADJn-GR77NzWG7uSh50tGQrgu6xI1xAg1unzKdhebzwH3+X3sP0hhxhOXswNBJFcRXcBAQ6jYtFEclEtG4vRabUgnW6fURx22DBYyAARNgAAwc4FjMZAA)